# jQuery mobile panel is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im trying to use jQuery mobile Panels to do a side menu.
I was reading documentation [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/).

And now Im trying to do my first example.
But nothing is happening when I click in my link to open the panel.

Do you see something wrong here?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<title>First Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Open</a> <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->       
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

My trying on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MG3QR/).

Comment: Because you aren't loading jQuery JS library. You should load it before JQM JS library. http://jsfiddle.net/MG3QR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents..you are inserting jQuery Mobile resources in the wrong order/place. In addition where is jQuery?

Here a working JSFiddle with jQuery Mobile already set up...[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H46zf/1/). If you click on the left button the panel will open or close.

In HTML section do as before.

```
<div data-role="page">    
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Cancel</a> <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->       
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Now, you should see content enriched correctly (the navigation bar only in this case) and you can manage the panel with

```
$( '#menu-panel' ).panel( "open" );
```

or

```
$( '#menu-panel' ).panel( "close" );
```

Comment: Thank you very much flexaddicted! By the way, do you know if its possible, I use jquery Mobile only for menu? Because I already have a project without jquery Mobile, and I want to adapt that project to mobile devices, and I already did everything, unless the menu...